# get asp:Label ToolTip using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tooltip

I have a simple problem with javascript and tooltip! I have a label in my page and I want to **get** it's tooltip using javascript. My label definition is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var label = document.getElementById('<%=lblTest.ClientID %>');
//alert(lable's tooltip)

</script>

<asp:Label ID="lblTest" ToolTip="Test ToolTip" Text="Test Text" runat="server" />
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code that you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert(label.title);
```

The ASP.NET control's Tooltip attribute maps to the HTML title attribute.

Comment: @mason ha..ha.. you were ahead by 7 sec :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`alert(label.title)`;